# insert array into tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, xcode4.3

I'm having trouble inserting an array to the table view. I have an array and i stored it in `alDescArray`.

Which is `alDescArray = (
    "Block1",
    "Block2",
    "Block3"
)` where its printed in through NSLog. The table doesn't show anything which part of my code when wrong?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSArray *BusRoute = alightDesc;
    int i;
    int count = [BusRoute count];
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {   
        NSDictionary *dic = [BusRoute objectAtIndex: i];
        NSDictionary *STEPS = [dic valueForKey:@"STEPS"];            
        alDescArray = [STEPS valueForKey:@"AlightDesc"];
   }
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

and this is the code for tableview

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [alDescArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [alDescArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
    return cell;
}
```

Pls help thanks

Comment: did you set the delegate of your tableView?

Comment: you need to retain you array Object alDescArray. like alDescArray = [[STEPS valueForKey:@"AlightDesc"] retain]

Comment: `[alDescArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`-> the elements inside the array are `NSStrings`?

Comment: Also one more thing, you need to check either your Table is registered for DataSource or not.

Comment: `YourHeader : ParentClass <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`   then `self.tableView.delegate = self;`

Comment: for the retain i set it at the .h file. `@property (retain, nonatomic)NSArray  *alDescArray;` am i wrong to do that?

Comment: its not a DataSource I'm just trying to put the array into the table where the array is taken out from JSON

Comment: @janusfidel that i have to link with the appdelegate?

Comment: that is not appdelegate but tableview's delegate. you must register your class as data source.

Comment: how should i set it? at the .h file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently your tableview's delegate / dataSource is not set.

.h

```
YourClassName : ParentClass <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    yourTableView.delegate = self;
    yourTableView.dataSource = self;
    NSArray *BusRoute = alightDesc;
    int i;
    int count = [BusRoute count];
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {   
        NSDictionary *dic = [BusRoute objectAtIndex: i];
        NSDictionary *STEPS = [dic valueForKey:@"STEPS"];            
        alDescArray = [STEPS valueForKey:@"AlightDesc"];
    }
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: ok thank. but i did what u said and it go another problem at: `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [alDescArray count];
}`

where the `return [alDescArray count];` got an error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0xc07e5e7b`

Comment: is it because of this array? `alDescArray = ( "Block1", "Block2", "Block3" )`

Comment: how did you declare the `alDescArray ` ?

Comment: yup. NSArray `*alightDesc;` and `@property (retain, nonatomic)NSArray  *alDescArray;`

Comment: ok solve thanks shouldn't use `@property (retain, nonatomic)NSArray *alDescArray;` should have use `alDescArray = [[STEPS valueForKey:@"AlightDesc"] retain]` @kapil Ghai